# IIS 8 gets corrupted on Windows Server 2012

Tags: windows-server-2012, iis-8, was

We configured IIS 8 on Windows Server 2012. Whenever we try to access any virtual directory, application pool will stop.

I tried iisreset and all other options. When i check windows services, I see WAS and W3SVC services are stopped.

When trying to start the service (WAS) it throws error
[image]

I even tried re-installing IIS, rebooting machine a couple of time but no luck.

Just to add, I have installed all latest windows update.

Has anyone faced this issue? Any workarounds?

I even tried re-configuring IIS using this [link](http://www.iis.net/learn/get-started/whats-new-in-iis-8/installing-iis-8-on-windows-server-2012)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oder of installation matters a lot. Before installing WCF components, I configured ASP.NET and related components.

After that I never faced issues.

1 more change IIS 8 does not support ASP.NET impersonate to be set to false.